# NodeJS - Replace module - SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Tags: replace, nodejs-server

The replace module is unexpectedly erroring on a very simple request.

I might as well post the answer when I work through this problem in case someone else encounters it.

```
Aviator@AW:/mnt/c/Users/Adrian/Desktop/Programming/nodejs_ex/NFP$ ls
easy-soap-example.js  nfp-easy-soap.js  noaa.xml  scratch.js
getFltList.js         nfp.html          raw.xml   test.js
Aviator@AW:/mnt/c/Users/Adrian/Desktop/Programming/nodejs_ex/NFP$ nodejs
> replace 'StdFromUtc' 'TEST' ./raw.xml
SyntaxError: Unexpected string
    at Object.exports.createScript (vm.js:24:10)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:225:25)
    at bound (domain.js:287:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:417:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:210:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:549:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:826:14)
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace

Example from documentation:

```
replace 'foo' 'bar' test/file1.js
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I was fooled. I thought npms were only for NodeJS (server), but in fact, this module added the functionality to my terminal (bash) and not to NodeJS .

It worked when I ran the CMD in bash and not from NodeJS.

```
Aviator@AW:/mnt/c/Users/Adrian/Desktop/Programming/nodejs_ex/NFP$ sed -n '18p' raw.xml
           <StdFromUtc>2021-09-29T00:00:00Z</StdFromUtc>
Aviator@AW:/mnt/c/Users/Adrian/Desktop/Programming/nodejs_ex/NFP$ replace 'StdFromUtc' 'TEST' ./raw.xml
./raw.xml
 18:                <TEST>2021-09-29T00:00:00Z</TEST>
Aviator@AW:/mnt/c/Users/Adrian/Desktop/Programming/nodejs_ex/NFP$
```